# Question about setInterval function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to a div to appear for 10 seconds at a time, every 1 minute.  So at the start of the minute, the div should appear for 10 seconds, go away, and then reappear again 50 seconds later, and on and on.

The only thing I have been able to figure out is how to make it disappear after 10 seconds.

```
$(function() {

    setInterval( function() { 
        hideMsg() 
    }, 10000);

    function hideMsg() {
        $('#header p').css('display', 'none');
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function() {

    showMsg();     
});
function showMsg()
{
   $('#header p').css('display', '');
   setTimeout(hideMsg, 10000);
}
function hideMsg(){
   $('#header p').css('display', 'none');
  setTimeout(showMsg, 60000);
}
```

This is it,

showMsg will show message end timeout will execute hideMsg after 10sec then hideMsg will hide msg and timeout will execute showMsg in 1 minute.

Comment: I thought of this too, but it does repeat hide message 6 times before it shows it, which may or may not be a problem. :P

Comment: it will just show it once, because timeout will execute only once. Check your javascript code, maybe you have copied function somewhere this code will work as its written 100%

Comment: Ah I see... I could have sworn those setTimeout calls were outside the show/hide functions :P

Comment: look at the revisions of my post and you will see they are not :)

Comment: oh no I know. It was my mistake.

Comment: Thanks a lot, a I really appreciate the fast answers.

Answer (score 1):

use setTimeout() function

```
$(function() {

    setInterval( function() { 
        hideMsg() 

    }, 10000);

    function showMsg(){

    }

    function hideMsg() {
        $('#header p').css('display', 'none');
        setTimeout(function(){
              $('#header p').css('display', 'block');
        }, 50000);
    }       
});
```

Comment: you need to add 50000 to setTimeout function

Answer (score 1):

```
function show(){
    // whatever your show code is

    // hide after 10 seconds
    setTimeout(function() {
                   // whatever your hide code is
              }, 10000); 
}

// invoke show every 60 seconds - show will hide itself after 10 seconds
var handle = window.setInterval(function() { show(); }, 60000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var messageTimer = setTimeout(showMsg, 50000);
function showMsg() {
    $('#header p').show();
    clearTimeout(messageTimer);
    messageTimer = setTimeout(hideMsg, 10000);
}
function hideMsg(){
    $('#header p').hide();
    clearTimeout(messageTimer);
    messageTimer = setTimeout(showMsg, 50000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What abou this?

```
   $(function() {
        var count = 0;
        setInterval( function() { 
            ++count % 6 ? $('#header p').hide() 
                        : $('#header p').show();
        }, 10000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to come up with something original using an interval timer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hideCnt = 0;    // 10 second interval cntr
    setInterval(function() {
        ++hideCnt;
        if (hideCnt >= 5) {
            $('#header p').toggle();
        }
        if (hideCnt >= 6) {
            hideCnt = 0;
        }
    }, 10000);
});
```

And a fiddle that shows the interval timer solution working: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/KReau/.

And here's the more traditional flavor:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function show() {
        $('#header p').show();
        setTimeout(hide, 50000);    // hide after 50 seconds
    }
    function hide() {
        $('#header p').hide();
        setTimeout(show, 10000);  // show after 10 seconds
    }
    show();
});
```